# regex, search and replace until a certain point

Tags: regex, perl, lookbehind

## The Problem

I have a file full of lines like

```
convert.these.dots.to.forward.slashes/but.leave.these.alone/i.mean.it
```

I want to search and replace such that I get

```
convert/these/dots/to/forward/slashes/but.leave.these.alone/i.mean.it
```

The . are converted to / up until the first forward slash

## The Question

How do I write a regex search and replace to solve my problem?

### Attempted solution

I tried using look behind with perl, but variable length look behinds are not implemented

```
$ echo "convert.these.dots.to.forward.slashes/but.leave.these.alone/i.mean.it" | perl -pe 's/(?<=[^\/]*)\./\//g'
Variable length lookbehind not implemented in regex m/(?<=[^/]*)\./ at -e line 1.
```

### Workaround

Variable length look aheads are implemented, so you can use this dirty trick

```
$ echo "convert.these.dots.to.forward.slashes/but.leave.these.alone/i.mean.it" | rev | perl -pe 's/\.(?=[^\/]*$)/\//g' | rev
convert/these/dots/to/forward/slashes/but.leave.these.alone/i.mean.it
```

Is there a more direct solution to this problem?

Comment: Split on `/` and replace all dots in the first group, and then join the parts ?

Comment: As @HamZaDzCyberDeV suggested, it may be easier to perform part of the process without using regex.

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV ok, how would you suggest an implementation of that given a linux shell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
s/\G([^\/.]*)\./\1\//g
```

`\G` is an assertion that matches the point at the end of the previous match. This ensures that each successive match immediately follows the last.

Matches:

```
\G          # start matching where the last match ended
([^\/.]*)   # capture until you encounter a "/" or a "."
\.          # the dot
```

Replaces with:

```
\1     # that interstitial text you captured
\/     # a slash
```

Usage:

```
echo "convert.these.dots.to.forward.slashes/but.leave.these.alone/i.mean.it" | perl -pe 's/\G([^\/.]*)\./\1\//g'

# yields: convert/these/dots/to/forward/slashes/but.leave.these.alone/i.mean.it
```

---

Alternatively, if you're a purist and don't want to add the captured subpattern back in — avoiding that may be more efficient, but I'm not certain — you could make use of `\K` to restrict the "real" match solely to the `.`, then simply replace with a `/`. `\K` essentially "forgets" what has been matched up to that point, so the final match ultimately returned is only what comes after the `\K`.

```
s/\G[^\/.]*\K\./\//g
```

Matches:

```
\G        # start matching where the last match ended
[^\/.]*   # consume chars until you encounter a "/" or a "."
\K        # "forget" what has been consumed so far
\.        # the dot
```

Thus, the entirety of the text matched for replacement is simply "`.`".

Replaces with:

```
\/      # a slash
```

Result is the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `substr` as an lvalue and perform the substitution on it. Or transliteration, like I did below.

```
$ perl -pe 'substr($_,0,index($_,"/")) =~ tr#.#/#'
convert.these.dots.to.forward.slashes/but.leave.these.alone/i.mean.it
convert/these/dots/to/forward/slashes/but.leave.these.alone/i.mean.it
```

This finds the first instance of a slash, extracts the part of the string before it, and performs a transliteration on that part.